# How naming objects returned by Controllers, Service and Repositories?

Tags: spring, naming-conventions

In Spring MVC we have 3 main categories of objects: `Controllers`, `Services` and `Repositories`.
I'm not able to "categorize" the objects returned by these three categories.
For example, the repositories return `Entity`s, but how could I name the objects returned by services and controllers?

In a real project I'm developing I have a repository returns an extraction from a table, so I get `Entities` objects. Into the service, where the logic is, I need only to return some fields, so I need to map the entities to another object-model. Later into the controller maybe I will need some layer specific presentation, for example between "standard-computer" and mobile, so I need another type of object to map the result of the service.

Answer (score 3):

Each layer has its postfix in the name of the `class` to keep the codebase clean and readable. In most of the projects I have worked on, the naming convention is:

**Controller layer**

The POJO exposed outside of the application, for example, thought a REST API is **DTO** (Data Transfer Object), so it is usually under the `dto` package, and the name is like `UserDto`

**Service layer**

The POJO that handles the application's business logic is called **domain** object, so it is usually under the `domain` package, and the name is like `User` without any postfix in the name.

**Repository layer**

The POJO that holds the data in the persistence layer is called **entity**, so it is usually under the `jpa` package, and the name is like `UserJpa`

Comment: Thanks. So seems there isn't a convention, only good habits.